# eclipse Command Line Shell plugin

Tags: eclipse, command-line, eclipse-plugin

Can anyone tell me which eclipse plugin this is? I've been searching all over the place but I can't find out what it's called. Thanks.

[image: Command Line Shell plugin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be this [Path Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/path-tools) ([Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/pathtools/)) plugin.

Comment: Yup that looks like it. Thanks for the fast response!